# I want to make a simple YouTube player in Android, but official examples do not work. I am lost, where should I start?

Tags: android, youtube, google-api, youtube-api, google-api-java-client

I am trying to make a sample app that can

- Search for a video on youtube given some text keywords
- List the results much as Youtube Android App does
- Play the selected video

So I started by googling how could I achieve this. I downloaded some samples, specially from [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/sample-applications) (they still use Eclipse, so imagine how up-to-date these examples must be), and they are all broken, they don't even work out of the box in my smartphone, which is a Samsung running 4.2.

So I made some more google and end up on other websites who have outdated code samples using previous versions of the API. And thus ended up on the same website... But now I tried reading the docs instead, so I started this pretty basic example [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list). I tried requesting something simple manually as they state using my own browser: https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=cats

And the response I am getting is:

```
    {
     "error": {
      "errors": [
       {
        "domain": "usageLimits",
        "reason": "dailyLimitExceededUnreg",
        "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.",
        "extendedHelp": "https://code.google.com/apis/console"
       }
      ],
      "code": 403,
      "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup."
     }
    }
```

While trying to understand this I have seen we have something about some auth key [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/register). What does this all mean? What limitations will google enforce upon my app with this authentication process? Is it like, my app will only be able to watch 100 videos per day? In a world where it may have 1000 users watching videos, so quickly depleting my daily limit?!

---

So in the end, I am very scared of reading infinite docs that will take me nowhere or wasting my time with outdated code examples which will also take me nowhere. What should I do? Why is this apparently so hard to use? If this API sucks are there other alternatives?

How did you learn this? So many youtube apps out there and I can't seem to understandthis. I feel quite dumb atm.

Comment: You have to create your own public key to use youtube-api. Here you have more info about it https://developers.google.com/youtube/registering_an_application

Comment: What limitations are born with it?

Comment: You have to check in console. I think it's 50k request per day.

Comment: For all instances of my app together world wide or for each instance?

Comment: I think it's for console. Console is connected with email address.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to access private data of the user, the easiest way would be to use an API key. Once you [register your project](https://developers.google.com/youtube/registering_an_application) and [set up your API key](https://developers.google.com/youtube/registering_an_application#Create_API_Keys), all you need to do is add `key=<your-API-key>` as a query parameter to your request. e.g. `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key=<your-API-key>&part=cats`

With regards to limits, you have a usage quota of 50 million per day, though different requests use different amounts of quota (the usage amount is documented for each request). That 50 million is shared by all users of your product. If you implement some basic caching for your requests, you shouldn't come anywhere near that limit unless you have hundreds of thousands of daily active users.

I've found following the docs is quite easy, once you get your first command going. Once you can get over the first item working, it's rather easy. This is the only way of accessing data from YouTube at this point in time. All the other ways have been deprecated and disabled.